# jquery focus on last loaded vuejs element

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js

hi im using vuejs to load some data this is the code

```
    add_line:function()
    {
        index = this.lines.length;
        this.lines.push({id:index});
        $('.search_and_select').last().focus();
    }
```

using this code its only focus the last element not in the current loaded like this picture
first picture is when i press add line but without focus in the element with class search_and_select
[image]
and this is the second picture
[image]
as you can see its not focus on the current added line its focus in the previous line 
and this is the search_and_select component

```
<search_and_select>
    <div slot='search_and_select' slot-scope="{change_keyword,results,no_result,chose_data,keyword,hidden_id,chose_first_value,default_value}">
        <div class="container">
            <input 
                name='chose_first_value[]'
                v-model="keyword"
                type="text" 
                {{$required ?? null}}
                class="{{$search_and_select}} o_input search_and_select"
                @keyup='change_keyword($event.target.value,"{{$type}}")'
            />
        </div>
    </div>
</search_and_select>
```

thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just add a `ref` prop to the input dynamically and then focus it when needed:

### Demo:

https://codepen.io/aQW5z9fe/pen/abvRzYO

```html
<input 
  v-for="line in lines"
  :key="line.ref"
  :ref="line.ref"
  v-model="line.model"
  :placeholder="line.ref"
/>
```

```js
data () {
  return {
    lines: [
      { 
        id: 0, 
        model: '',
        ref: 'input0' 
      }
    ]
  } 
},
methods: {
  addLine () {
    let index = this.lines.length
    // Add ref dynamically
    this.lines.push({ 
      id: index, 
      model: '',
      ref: `input${index}` 
    })
    // Focus added input
    this.$nextTick(() => {
      this.$refs[`input${index}`][0].focus()
    })
  }
}
```